# Comprehension check: Characteristic Polynomials, T-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I think I have a decent grasp on characteristic polynomials, but want to make sure I am correct on the following.

Let's say we have the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients whose degree is at most $3$: $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$. We have the transformation $T(f(x))=f''(x)$. I am first asked to compute a basis for the $T$-invariant subspace generated by $x^3$. Therefore, I compute $T(x^3)=6x$ and $T^2(x^3)=0$. Therefore, a basis for this $T$-invariant subspace (call it $W$) is $\{x^3,6x\}$. Now, the matrix representation of $T_W$ with respect to this basis is (I think) just $I_2.$ Hence, the characteristic polynomial is $\chi_{T_W}(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^2$.

I think I am confused by the the fact that given any basis obtained in this manner, the matrix representation of $T_W$ would always be an identity matrix corresponding to the size of the basis. Therefore, the characteristic polynomial could only ever be $(1-\lambda)^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. (This just seems odd)

Comment: Everything looks good until you say that the matrix rep. is $I_2$. If that were the case then $T(x^3)$ would be $x^3$. Maybe go review the basics of how to figure out the matrix rep. for a linear transformation?

Comment: @JonathanZ that makes sense. But if the representation is with respect to this basis and $W$ is $2$-dimensional, the matrix should be $2\times 2$ still?

Comment: Yes, since you're considering the restriction of $T$ to a 2-dimensional (sub-)space, you'll get s $2 x 2$ matrix.

Comment: This might help: You've got a basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$, where $e_1$ is $x^3$ and $e_2$ is $6x$. You have to find $a$ and $b$ such that $T(e_1) = a e_1 + b e_2$ to get one row of your matrix. Does that get you started?

Comment: @JonathanZ, that does make sense, thank you. So in this context, $T_W(x^3)=6x$ which we set equal to $ax^3+b(6x).$ Therefore, we get $a=0, b=1$. Similarly, for $T_W (6x)$, we get $a'=0, b'=0$. So the matrix is zeros everywhere except for the bottom left corner, where it is a $1$?

Comment: Yup, you've got it.